# How to a get a list generated by a web page to my host machine using python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

i want to have a list from a website to my machine but i can't just copy paste it. So when i go to the console and type the list name, it shows me the list. I want to have this list to my machine. I think I can do this using python somehow? Here is what the list looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvkxW.png) . Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: do you want to scrape data from a website?

Comment: @JasperNicholMFabella I want to have that array to a, say, python dictionary ? so i can do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using `beautiful soup` to scrape that list . read the docs [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Thanks! It leads me to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list as it is now - and you don't want it to be updated when the website changes - then you can convert the data to JSON, copy that string to your code and parse it again. Depending on what data is stored in the array you may not even need to parse it again as the JSON could well be valid Python.

**Browser's console**

```js
// Assuming your array is named bytes
JSON.stringify(bytes)
```

**Python**

```py
import json
BYTES_AS_JSON = "[1,2,3,4,5]"
bytes = json.loads(BYTES_AS_JSON)
```